# Raspberry PI 3 - UV4L w/ raspicam driver KO after upgrading

Tags: video-streaming, raspbian, uv4l

I'm developping an embedded car CCTV using UV4L server and the Raspicam driver. running the command

```
uv4l --driver raspicam --width=320 --height=240 --framerate=20 --rotation=0 --server-option --port=8090 --auto-video_nr --encoding=h264
```

was working perfectly until I upgraded the UV4L software. The video stream is now  frozen and I can't even kill the job using kill -9.

I've checked this on 3 differents raspberry PI (ARMV71) as all video streams are now KO I'm quiet sure that the issue was upgrading from

```
ii  uv4l                               1.9.13                            armhf        User space Video4Linux Framework Core
ii  uv4l-raspicam                      1.9.50                            armhf        CSI Camera Board driver for any Raspberry Pi.
ii  uv4l-raspicam-extras               1.34                              armhf        Extras for the CSI Camera Board driver for Raspberry Pi.
ii  uv4l-server                        1.1.97                            armhf        Streaming Server module for UV4L with HTTP/HTTPS front-end.
```

to

```
ii  uv4l                               1.9.13                            armhf        User space Video4Linux Framework Core
ii  uv4l-raspicam                      1.9.53                            armhf        CSI Camera Board driver for any Raspberry Pi.
ii  uv4l-raspicam-extras               1.35                              armhf        Extras for the CSI Camera Board driver for Raspberry Pi.
ii  uv4l-server                        1.1.98                            armhf        Streaming Server module for UV4L with HTTP/HTTPS front-end.
```

so that relies on uv4l-raspicam 1.9.50 -> 1.9.53 and/or the uv4l-server 1.1.97 -> 1.1.98 upgrades.

Note : the camera is Ok as I can see movies using raspivid ...

Has anybody already experienced this .. and how to fix ? .. I didn't succeeded trying to rollback the version

Answer (score 0):

Update the `uv4l-raspicam` driver to version v1.54 to fix the regression. It's a pity it's not possible to comment the question with this short answer.